# Installing ubuntu 14.04 or higher on PCIe G3x4 SSD with Windows pre-installed

Tags: ssd, gparted, asus

I just recently bought [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01578ZN0Q) laptop with Windows 10 pre-installed in it on the SSD. I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 on this SSD (does not matter if I have to remove Windows for that) and use 1 TB HDD to store data.

The problem I am having right now is that Ubuntu installer does not detect SSD, it only shows 1 TB HDD. I have tried different versions of Ubuntu (14.04, 15.04, 15.10) but the same problem is there. Also, GParted (latest version with support for NVMe devices) is not able to show the SSD but Windows shows both SSD and HDD. SSD has NVMe controller type and PCIe as controller interface whereas HDD has AHCI controller type and SATA as controller interface and the SATA Configuration is RAID. There is no option in UEFI to change any of these options.

I am not able to figure out why the SSD is not being shown on Ubuntu installer or GParted. Does anyone have any idea what can be the reason?

**EDIT :** It looks like it might be because Intel Rapid Storage Technology (RST) is enabled. Can this be the reason that GParted and Ubuntu is not able to see the SSD? There is no option to disable it from the UEFI. How can I disable it from Windows 10? Also, only windows can see SSD and it has Windows OS installed on it.. Is it possible that it is locked so that no one else can see it? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was likely caused by [this bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=755022) in GParted. That bug was fixed in version 0.24.0 on October 27th, 2015. Please try again with a newer version of GParted and you should no longer have any problems!

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to disable secure boot on your laptop. Startup your laptop and go into the BIOS - this is usually F2/F10 key. Change the setting in boot to disable secure boot and disable UEFI if its enabled. Use the legacy mode to install. When the Ubuntu install screen appears it will automatically setup the system with UEFI if its available.

If the above does not help, then you need to remove the disk from the laptop and put it into an another laptop or an usb 2 enclosure to find out if the disk is alright.

Comment: Secure boot is already disabled and it has UEFI available. I don't think it has legacy mode. I feel that chances of disk being bad is pretty less as I just bought this laptop couple of days back. Thanks!